# Transparent navbar on bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want o make a navbar to be transparent, I have the following code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="top:50px; background:transparent;">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <a class="navbar-brand">My Company</a>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portofolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So I used `background:transparent;` but the result is this:

[image]

There is a white line on top and an even bigger white line on top of the navbar. How can I remove that? Or how can I have transparent navbar?

Comment: Check if there is any border at all for the navbar or any of its containing elements with the developer tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `border:0;` and `box-shadow:none`

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">  
            <div class="container">
                 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">   
                      <a class="navbar-brand">My Company</a> 
                      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Portofolio</a></li> 
                      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                 </ul>  
           </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE** Proper way of adding CSS:

```
.navbar-default{
    background:none !important;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow:none !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rpE9E/)

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

That is the `border`. Try add `border: none !important` to the element.

If not, please provide a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so I can take a look at it.